# Extract rhythmic pattern from javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, pattern-recognition

I am attempting to write a script which can recognize a rhythmic pattern within an array of numbers.

This script would take an array of numbers as input. It would output a starting number and increment for the most likely correlation.

Example:

Given an array:

`[10,19,20,30,39,61,61,70,82,100,101,101,105,109,110,120]`

It would output

```
start: 10
increment: 10
```

because the best matching pattern for the above data is an increment of 10: `[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120]`

Is something like this possible? Are there standard techniques that I can look at to accomplish this? Thank you!

**EDIT**

This is for finding a rhythm within a dataset of many (thousands) of "guesses" as to what millisecond a downbeat is occurring.

Therefore, a best-matching pattern would be a linear pattern, yes.

However, it occurs to me that the tempo may vary slightly throughout the dataset. Therefore, a different approach may be needed -- one which identifies individual hotspots based on an interpretation of this dataset as a kind of heatmap.

Yes it is possible that this is more a math question and could be closed. I am just a bit lost on it.

Comment: 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression 2. http://dracoblue.net/dev/linear-least-squares-in-javascript/

Comment: Define "best matching pattern"

Comment: As with others, "best matching" is vague. A simple linear regression (that would also be a least squares solution) would get an average, then increment based on that. However, a sine curve may fit better, or parabola, or some other curve.

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about general mathematics (or statistical analysis) than javascript programming.

Comment: Can linear regression be applied to a one-dimensional dataset?